# Subscribe to Meteor.users() both listing all users and this.userId

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

PAGE CUSTOMERS: Lists all users in the users collection.
PAGE PROFILE: List only logged in user profile information.

## userProfiles.js:

```
 if (Meteor.isServer) {
   Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find({}, {
        fields: {
          // VISIBLE
          'profile.mobile': 1,
          'profile.zipcode': 1,
          'profile.first_name': 1,
          'profile.work_title': 1,
          'emails[0].address': 1,
        }});
    });
 }
```

## profile.js

```
Template.profileDetails.helpers({
  user: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
  },

  userEmail: function() {
    return this.emails[0].address;
  },

  userFirstName: function() {
    return this.profile.first_name;
  },

  userTitle: function() {
    return this.profile.work_title;
  },

  userMobile: function() {
    return this.profile.mobile;
  },

  userZip: function() {
    return this.profile.zipcode;
  },
});
```

## customers.js

```
Template.customerDetails.helpers({
  user: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find();
  },

  userEmail: function() {
    return this.emails[0].address;
  },

  userFirstName: function() {
    return this.profile.first_name;
  },

  userTitle: function() {
    return this.profile.work_title;
  },

  userMobile: function() {
    return this.profile.mobile;
  },

  userZip: function() {
    return this.profile.zipcode;
  },
});
```

The profile page is not showing any information at all. How can i get it to only display the logged in user information? Thank you!

Comment: PS! If the publish code is:
return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
It works the other way around.

Comment: Why do your `profile.js` and `customers.js` files both define `Template.customerDetails.helpers` (i.e. for the same template with name "customerDetails")?

Comment: That was just an error on my part editing it in StackOverflow. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "this" in the helpers isn't the user. since you're looking for the current user in your profile template, you can do it in Blaze, without a helper:

```
{{currentUser.profile.first_name}}
```

for the customers, you can loop over the users returned by your helper. i would rename the helper:

```
Template.customerDetails.helpers({
  customers(){
    return Meteor.users.find({});
  }
});
```

then you can loop over them, in Blaze, like this:

```
{{#each customer in customers}}
  {{customer.profile.first_name}}
{{else}}
   No customers found.
{{/each}}
```

note that you don't need any other helpers to make that work.

c.f. http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-in

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: How do i shorten my helpers with multiple fields?

user: function() {
    var email = return Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
    var someThingElse = return Meteor.user().someThingElse;

And then use {{user.someThingElse}} ? Thank you

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. one benefit of doing it in Blaze as i've shown is it takes care of the null checks. if you were to write those helpers, you'd have to handle that yourself, and that makes the code more lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

To get the currently logged-in user, you could use: `Meteor.user()`:

```
//...
user: function() {
  return Meteor.user();
},
//...
```